# Logging to JettyLogger(null)

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty, google-plugin-eclipse

when I run my application as an app engine web application, in the  log console I have that line:

```
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
```

console waits about 5-7 second on this line. may be because of "null", what do you think? what is this, and how can I fix that?

Comment: It's an INFO level event, ignore it.

Comment: but it thinks for about 5 second at this line :-) I don't like that :)